# Angular - how do I get data to load with ngOnChanges

Tags: angular, typescript, d3.js, angular-changedetection, ngonchanges

I have a [demo here](https://stackblitz.com/edit/d3-stacked-chart-dynamic-scales-n3zykv?file=src%2Fapp%2Fchart.ts)

It's a angular app where I'm trying to create a D3 chart.

The chart data is created with a createDate function, creating random data and dates.

I want the chart to update with the update button so I'm using ngOnChanges but this doesn't create the chart when the pages load.

The ngOnInit commented out loads the chart on page load.

```
ngOnChanges(changes: SimpleChanges) {
    if(!changes.data) return;

    if(this.hasPreviousData){

      this.createData()

      this.stack = d3.stack()
          .keys(['data_1', 'data_2', 'data_3', 'data_4'])

      this.createStack(this.testData);
    }else{

      this.createData()

      this.stack = d3.stack()
        .keys(['data_1', 'data_2', 'data_3', 'data_4'])

      this.initScales();
      this.initSvg();
      this.drawAxis();
      this.createStack(this.testData);

      this.hasPreviousData = true;
    }
  }
```

Comment: I do not see any graph getting plotted in the attached stacklitz example. Can you please verify

Comment: Thats my issue, if you comment out the ngOnChanges and uncomment the ngOnInit you will see the the chart, but I want it to work with ngOnChanges

Comment: Good question. Check out my answer and let me know if it helped.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason `ngOnChanges` is not working because it works on `@Input` param changes. In your case, **you are simply changing the value of the component from the component itself**.

[Take a look at this demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/d3-stacked-chart-dynamic-scales-ep4hqb?file=src/app/chart.ts). I have made some code changes in your demo code and it seems to be doing the same thing which you are expecting.

You can put the graph creation logic in the `createData()` itself and rest is handled:

```
  createData() {
    this.testData = [];
    this.years = Math.floor(Math.random() * this.dates.length)
    console.log(this.years)
    for(let i:number= 0; i<=this.years; i++){
      this.testData[i] = {
        data_1: Math.floor(Math.random() * (this.max - this.min)),
        data_2: Math.floor(Math.random() * (this.max - this.min)),
        data_3: Math.floor(Math.random() * (this.max - this.min)),
        data_4: Math.floor(Math.random() * (this.max - this.min)),
        date: this.dates[i]
      }
    }    
    this.stack = d3.stack()
      .keys(['data_1', 'data_2', 'data_3', 'data_4']);
    if(this.hasPreviousData){
      this.createStack(this.testData);
    }else{
      this.hasPreviousData = true;
      this.initScales();
      this.initSvg();
      this.drawAxis();
      this.createStack(this.testData);
    }
  }
```

Comment: @Enthu : Sure. let me check

Comment: @ShashankVivek I have the similar issue  here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57666947/get-data-on-the-component-load with the ngOnChanges not letting to get the data on Page/Component Load, can you please help with that.